# macOS Big Sur - Anyone can get a take of the unlocked screen on a locked locked MacBook?

Tags: security, big-sur, lockscreen, macos

On my MacBook running macOS Big Sur 11.0.1, I set one of the hot corners to 'Put Display to Sleep' (in Desktop & Sreen Saver settings) and set the Mac to 'required password `immediately` after sleep or screen saver begins' (in Security and Privacy -> General).

When I put the display to sleep with the hot corner, the display goes to sleep and the Mac is locked. The screen goes dark. But if I move my finger on the trackpad, the unlocked screen is shown for ~0.1 seconds before the login window is shown, giving anyone a chance to see what's on the unlocked screen without authentication with a password or Touch ID.

Is it just me or is it a bug affecting many people?

Note that this bug cannot be reproduced if you lock your Mac with cmd-control-Q or from the menu bar.

Comment: I've not observed this

Comment: I think there is a small technical difference between `Display Sleep` and `Sleep`. I noticed that running `pmset -g` in terminal lists different values for Display Sleep, Disk Sleep and Sleep. What triggers `Sleep` after entering `Display Sleep` I am not sure about, but may be the reason your desktop briefly shows up before the log in window. I personally don't use that hot corner, but instead have a Screensaver hot corner which works correctly. Sorry I couldn't be of more help there.

Comment: I have also experienced this on an M1 MacBook Air.